# Почему у меня вылезает ошибка unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, python-3.x

когда я хотел запустить код "Hangman" у меня вылезла ошибка "unindent does not match any outer indentation level". Как это исправить? Помогите пожалуйста.

```
import random
HANGMAN_PICS = ['''
  +---+
      |
      |
      |
     ===''', '''
  +---+
  0   |
      |
      |
     ===''', '''
  +---+
  0   |
  |   |
      |
     ===''', '''
  +---+
  0   |
 /|   |
      |
     ===''', '''
  +---+
  0   |
 /|\  |
      |
     ===''', '''
  +---+
  0   |
 /|\  |
 /    |
     ===''', '''
  +---+
  0   |
 /|\  |
 / \  |
     ===''']
words = 'аист акула бабуин баран барсук бобр бык верблюд волк воробей ворон выдра голубь гусь жаба зебра змея индюк кит кобра коза козёл койот корова кошка кролик крыса курица лама ласка лебедь лев лиса лосось лось лягушка медведь моллюск моль мул муравей мышь норка носорог обезьяна овца окунь олень орёл осёл панда паук питон попугай пума семга скунс собака сова тигр тритон тюлень утка форель хорёк черепаха ястреб ящерица'.split()

def getRandomWord(wordList):
    # Эта функция возращает случайную строку из переданного списка.
    wordIndex = random.randint(0, len(wordList) - 1)
    return wordList[wordIndex]

def displayBoard(missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord):
    print(HANGMAN_PICS[len(missedLetters)])
    print()

    print('Ошибочные буквы:', end=' ')
    for letter in missedLetters:
        print(letter, end=' ')
    print()

    blanks = '_' * len(secretWord)

    for i in range(len(secretWord)): # заменяет пропуски отгаданными буквами
        if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
            blanks = blanks[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i+1:]

    for letter in blanks: # Показывает секретное слово с пробелами между буквами
        print(letter, end=' ')
    print()

def getGuess(alreadyGuessed):
    # Возращает букву, введённую игроком. Эта функция проверяет, что игрок ввёл только одну букву и ничего больше.
       while True:
           print('Введите букву.')
           guess = input()
           guess = guess.lower()
           if len(guess) != 1:
               print('Пожалуйста, введите одну букву.')
           elif guess in alreadyGuessed:
               print('Вы уже называли эту букву. Назовите другую.')
           elif guess not in 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя':
               print('Пожалуйста, введите БУКВУ.')
           else:
               return guess

def playAgain():
    # Эта функция возращает значение True, если игрок хочет сыграть заново; в противном случае возращает False.
      print('Хотите сыграть ещё? (да или нет)')
      return input().lower().startswith('д')


print('В И С Е Л И Ц А')
missedLetters = ''
correctLetters = ''
secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
gameIsDone = False

while True:
    displayBoard(missedLetters, correctletters, secretWord)

    # Позволяет игроку ввести букву.
    guess = getGuess(missedLetters + correctLetters)

    if guess in secretWord:
        correctLetters = correctLetters + guess

        # Проверяет, выйграл ли игрок.
        foundAllletters = True
        for i in range(len(secretWord)):
            if secretWord[i] not in correctLetters:
                foundAllLetters = False
                break
            if foundAllLetters:
                print('ДА! Секретное слово - "' + secretWord + '"! Вы угадали!')
                gameIsDone = True

            else:
                missedLetters + guess

                # Проверяет, превысил ли игрок лимит попыток и проиграл.
               if len(missedLetters) == len(HANGMAN_PICS - 1:
                    displayBoard(missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)
                    print('У вас не осталось попыток!\nПосле '+str(len(missedLetters))+' ошибок и '+str(len(correctLetters))+'угаданных букв. Загаданное слово:'+secretWord+'"')
                   gameIsDone = True

        # Запрашивает, хочет ли игрок сыграть заново.
       if gameIsDone:
           if playAgain():
               missedLetters = ''
               correctLetters = ''
               gameIsDone = False
               secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
           else:
               break
```

Comment: В какой строке возникает ошибка?

Comment: Как минимум у вас комментарии поехавшие местами, хотя не уверен, что это влияет.

Answer (score 0):

```
        else:
            missedLetters + guess

            # Проверяет, превысил ли игрок лимит попыток и проиграл.
           if len(missedLetters) == len(HANGMAN_PICS - 1:
```

1. Не закрыта скобка перед двоеточием
2. `if` зачем-то сдвинут на один символ левее чем предыдущие строки, на что и ругается Питон сейчас
3. Значение выражения `missedLetters + guess` никуда не присваивается, зачем оно?

И у вас там таких непонятных сдвигов строки влево несколько штук по коду. Для Питона это важно, у него сдвиги означают блок кода, неправильный сдвиг - ошибка.

```
correctLetters = ''
...
    displayBoard(missedLetters, correctletters, secretWord)
```

Тут у вас переменная `correctLetters` с большой буквой `L`, а вызываете вы функцию когда передаёте переменную с маленькой буквой `l`.

Comment: Я проверил, теперь у меня пишет `NameError: name 'correctletters' is not defined` после того как я запускаю код

Comment: @TikiMan Добавил в ответ

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё работает